# table in Athena not update with vpc logs

Tags: amazon-athena, vpc

I have VPC flow log which the destination for it is S3, with S3 bucket = vpc_logs. under this bucket, the vpc records are upload under the folder AWSLogs/accountId/vpcflowlogs/region/year/month/day/log_file_name.log.gz.
I want to be able to view the records with Athena as suggested in AWS but the query suggested is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vpc_flow_logs (
  version int,
  account string,
  interfaceid string,
  sourceaddress string,
  destinationaddress string,
  sourceport int,
  destinationport int,
  protocol int,
  numpackets int,
  numbytes bigint,
  starttime int,
  endtime int,
  action string,
  logstatus string
)  
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/AWSLogs/account_id/vpcflowlogs/region/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

then when i want to view my record, i am getting 0 records. I believe cause that the information located under the folders.. this is right query to run?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your table is not fetching you any records is the s3 directory structure that you are following.As your table is partitioned and if you want Athena to automatically detect the partitions then the s3 directory structure should be like below :

```
s3://AWSLogs/.../.../.../year=2018/month=01/day=01/
```

If you have above key value pair structure in s3 then after the table created, partitions can be automatically added using below query:

```
msck repair table vpc_flow_logs
```

If you don't have control over the directory structure then refer to "**Partition Your Data in Athena for Improved Query Performance and Reduced Costs**" in this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-vpc-flow-logs-with-amazon-kinesis-firehose-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/) which explains how to add partitions when you don't have hive style partitioning directory structure.

One more simpler but little expensive way is to run a [crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) which will automatically create table and partitions even you have below directory structure.All you need to do is pass "    s3://AWSLogs/accountId/vpcflowlogs/region/" to your crawler as input.

```
s3://.../.../.../.../year/month/day/
```

Comment: if I want to avoid to search by specific date, I need to remove the partition? I want to be able to get full data.

Comment: Yes that should work.But if your data is huge then you might end up scanning huge amount of data if you want to even search for specific date.

Comment: @meital Can you mark it answered if this solution helped in solving your problem ?